# How to use testdisk on external hard drive that freezes whenever connected?

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, freeze, mybook

I've been trying to recover files from my WD external hard drive, and nothing has worked so far. I've heard of testdisk but I can't use it because as soon as I connect my external, it freezes the PC.

Comment: Use Hirens Boot like what I told you before.

Comment: There's a TestDisk on it.

Comment: There's a lot of HDD Recovery Tools to choose from. Try it and see it for yourself.

Comment: Why do I need Hirens Boot if I alread have testdisk downloaded? Can you tell me step by step please?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.pendriveapps.com/testdisk-free-portable-data-recovery/

Comment: Your PC freezes because Windows is retrying to read the HDD and doesn't succeed. You can bypass this problem if you don't boot in Windows, like when you use Hirens Boot. If you are not complete sure what you are doing consider sending the drive to a data recovery specialist. Recovering data is not as easy and if you aren't completely certain what you are doing you might cause more damage to the data. Have a look at the list of [WD Data Recovery Partners](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=ac7K14).

Comment: So what do i do in Hirens Boot when I load it up?